# Cassandra DataStax driver: how to page through columns

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have wide rows with timestamp columns. If I use the DataStax Java driver, I can page row results by using LIMIT or FETCH_SIZE, however, I could not find any specifics as to how I can page through columns for a specific row.

I found this post: http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/CQL-3-and-wide-rows-td7594577.html
which explains how I could get ranges of columns based on the column name (timestamp) values.

However, what I need to do is to get ALL columns, I just don't want to load them all into memory , but rather "stream" the results and process a chunk of columns (preferably of a controllable size) at a time until all columns of the row are processed.
Does the DataStax driver support streaming of this kind? and of so - what is the syntax for using it?

Additional clarification:
Essentially, what I'm looking for is an equivalent of the Hector's ColumnSliceIterator using which I could iterate over all columns (up to Integer.MAX_VALUE number) of a specific row in batches of, say, 100 columns at a time as following:

```
SliceQuery sliceQuery = HFactory.createSliceQuery(keySpace, ...);
sliceQuery.setColumnFamily(MY_COLUMN_FAMILY);
sliceQuery.setKey(myRowKey);
// columns to be returned. The null value indicates all columns
sliceQuery.setRange(
    null // start column
    , null // end column
    , false // reversed order
    , Integer.MAX_VALUE // number of columns to return
);

ColumnSliceIterator iter = new ColumnSliceIterator( 
    sliceQuery // previously created slice query needs to be passed as parameter
    , null // starting column name
    , null // ending column name
    , false // reverse
    , 100 // column count <-- the batch size 
);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String myColumnValue = iter.next().getValue();
}
```

How do I do the exact same thing using the DataStax driver?

thanks!

Marina

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ResultSet](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html) Object that you get is actually setup to do this sort of paginating for you by default. Calling `one()` repeatedly or iterating using the `iterator()` will allow you to access all the data without calling it all into memory at once. More details are available in the api.

Comment: thanks, @RussS, I've already looked through this API doc and coudl not find any confirmation that paging is happening over columns in one row... In fact, iterator() and one() method signatures have Row as the data type , and from reading the doc it seems they are talking about getting one Row, and iterating over Rows as the unit of work, not columns... Am I missing something here? Here is the doc for ResultSet.one() method: "Returns:
the next row in this resultSet or null if this ResultSet is exhausted"

Comment: The rows here are the logical rows not the C* wide rows

Comment: Like with a table ( X text, y text, z text , PK ( X,Y))
X1 => Y1:Z1, Y2:Z2, Y3:Z3, Y4:Z4
The driver will be auto buffering parts of the whole row X1 in chunks like first pulling 
{Y1:Z1, Y2:Z2} into memory.
Then once you call one() twice or iterate past Y2 it know it needs new data in the buffer and will next chunk of values
{Y3:Z3, Y4:Z4}
and so on till you are done.

Comment: I see. So in effect it means that setFetchSize() will control the number of columns (cells) that each one() method will return, right? Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Also note you may have multiple cells in the logical row but this is basically whats going on :)